# Database View in Oracle 9i with SDE 9.3.1

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, database, oracle-dbms

If I have a sql statement creating a view against ArcSDE 9.3.1 on Oracle 9i, is the best practice to create the view in ArcCatalog just creating the name (kind of shell of the view) then going in to PLSQL to modify the view?  What are the best practices on this?

Reading this.. http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Using_database_views ..I am still left without great advice.  Thanks.

Here is the view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SERIES_DETAIL AS
SELECT LineLoop.LineName, Cont_StationSeries.EventID AS RouteID, Eng_StationSeries.EventID AS SeriesID, Eng_StationSeries.SeriesOrder, Eng_StationSeries.BeginStation, Eng_StationSeries.EndStation, Begin_Cont_ControlPoint.StationValue AS BeginMeasure, End_Cont_ControlPoint.StationValue AS EndMeasure

FROM (((((LINELOOP LineLoop INNER JOIN STATIONSERIES Cont_StationSeries ON LineLoop.EventID=Cont_StationSeries.LineLoopEventID) INNER JOIN STATIONSERIES Eng_StationSeries ON LineLoop.EventID=Eng_StationSeries.LineLoopEventID) INNER JOIN CONTROLPOINT Begin_Eng_ControlPoint ON (Eng_StationSeries.BeginStation=Begin_Eng_ControlPoint.StationValue) AND (Eng_StationSeries.EventID=Begin_Eng_ControlPoint.StationSeriesEventID)) INNER JOIN CONTROLPOINT End_Eng_ControlPoint ON (Eng_StationSeries.EndStation=End_Eng_ControlPoint.StationValue) AND (Eng_StationSeries.EventID=End_Eng_ControlPoint.StationSeriesEventID)) INNER JOIN CONTROLPOINT End_Cont_ControlPoint ON End_Eng_ControlPoint.GroupEventID=End_Cont_ControlPoint.GroupEventID) INNER JOIN CONTROLPOINT Begin_Cont_ControlPoint ON Begin_Eng_ControlPoint.GroupEventID=Begin_Cont_ControlPoint.GroupEventID

WHERE (((Cont_StationSeries.SubTypeCD)=1) AND ((Eng_StationSeries.SubTypeCD)=2) AND ((Begin_Eng_ControlPoint.SubTypeCD)=2) AND ((End_Eng_ControlPoint.SubTypeCD)=2) AND ((Begin_Cont_ControlPoint.SubTypeCD)=1) AND ((End_Cont_ControlPoint.SubTypeCD)=1))

ORDER BY LineLoop.LineName, Cont_StationSeries.EventID, Eng_StationSeries.SeriesOrder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I have seen to do it is to use the commandline tools to create the stub of the view; then use the RDBMS tools to expand the view. This allows you to use more visual tools to do this; since the tools in the ESRI platform are lacking.

Comment: Does creating the view in ArcCatalog make the view a static view..someone is trying to convince me of this and I can't find any documentation.  Also, I can't readily create a view for testing with out getting the entire IT DBA team mobilized and ......thanks.

Comment: You can't create a spatial view from ArcCatalog by default, you can use the GDBT to do some things but I have not seen much sucess there. A view would never be static, it always looks to the spatial tables you are building against.